# Need a fairly "rude" program exit

Tags: c++, windows, qt, modal-dialog, terminate

Environment is Windows 7.  We have a program (written in C++ and employing a fairly old [circa 2000] version of Qt) that needs to monitor a service (written in java) on the same PC.  The program opens a socket connection to the service and the two continuously chat about nothing in particular (the socket connection itself indicates omnia praeclara).

If that service raises an alert, either by closing the socket, or through some other means, I require the C++ program to display a message and then halt and terminate.  It would be nice to do this as obtrusively as possible (I know, not your regular fare).

What I would like to learn, is how to have the program raise a dialog or window of some description, occupying the full screen, onto which I could print a message.  Equally viable, would be to have a dialog raised in the fashion of the UAC dialog (which kinda dims the screen and takes over, forcing you to deal with it).  After a timeout (will leave it on there for several minutes), it will unceremoniously terminate the program.  Kersplat!

I know about using MessageBox (or QMessageBox) to display little bits of info, with the Ok button to acknowledge, but those are neither fullscreen nor (can't think of the word, but they're not "taking over the interface").

I know this is a rude and horrible way to deal with program exit... I am deliberately intending it to be.  The machines are in a location where the user may have stepped away and there needs to be some form of irritant presented which will eventually force them to call for assistance.

Comment: The most brutal way to kill your program would be [`std::abort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort). It will call no destructors, just shut your program down and return some code for unsuccessful execution to the OS.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to detect that the socket has closed, how to make a full screen Qt window, or how to exit the current process gracefully or not?

Comment: Edited the third para.  Need a fullscreen dialog/window, that does not permit the user to Alt-tab away.  Can be done using Qt or standard windows controls.  I know how to close the socket, not worried about that.

Comment: The key word you need to use in your searches is ***modal***. There's *application modal* where you can't access the application until dealing with the popup, but it sounds like you're looking for a system-wide modal window.

Comment: @Jon - For the full-screen part, have you tried QWidget::showFullScreen(), e.g., on a QMainWindow?

Comment: `FatalAppExit` is fairly rude. Okay in Windows 8 it doesn't *look* that dangerous (an ordinary info-box), but it does stay on top.

Comment: @AndyThomas After making some vain attempts for the last hours, I've decided I'd really rather not use Qt.  Prefer a windows solution if one can be concocted.  How do people make those UAC style prompts?  That's what I'd really like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it appears that this is not really doable, in a standard way, using a nice API.  Seems MS doesn't like modal dialogs and pausing the system (for good reason).  We need to though, so the best I could come up with, was the following, based on what I found [here](http://developex.com/blog/system-modal-back/).  Create a second desktop, switch to that and pop up the messagebox.  I would have preferred a dialog with no interactivity (would have timed out after, oh, say 5-10 minutes - rude!) but this will do for now.  Even makes a dimmed background ala the UAC dialog.

This really should go into a modal dialog class for general use. This program is using Qt, hence the signal in the first part of the TerminateProgram method.

```
// This, and the background window proc, are declared static in header.
HDC ServiceMonitorThread::hBKDC;

void ServiceMonitorThread::TerminateProgram()
{
   unsigned int errorCode = 0x0a000000;
   string caption = "Error";
   string message = "In defiance of the gods, an error occurred!";

   // Emit the signal which will instruct the other parts of the program to stop doing what they are doing.
   emit ErrorOccurred();

   // Create the background for the error desktop
   CreateBackgroundBitmap();

   // Save the handle to the current desktop
   HDESK hDeskOld = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

   // Create a new desktop
   HDESK hDesk = CreateDesktop("ErrorDialogDT", NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
   SwitchDesktop(hDesk);

   // Assign new desktop to the current thread
   SetThreadDesktop(hDesk);

   // Adjust the background to be not black.
   CreateBackgroundWindow();

   // Create and display the error dialog on the new desktop.
   MessageBox(NULL, 
              message.c_str(),
              caption.c_str(), 
              MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);

   // Switch back to the initial desktop
   SwitchDesktop(hDeskOld);
   CloseDesktop(hDesk);

   ::exit(errorCode);
}

// Takes a screenshot of the current desktop, dims it, then stores it 
// for display on the secondary desktop.
void ServiceMonitorThread::CreateBackgroundBitmap()
{
   // Retrieve desktop size
   RECT rcDesktop = {0};
   GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rcDesktop);

   // Prepare context for background
   HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
   hBKDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
   HGDIOBJ hBitmapBKOld = SelectObject(hBKDC, CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom));

   // Grab a screenshot from current desktop
   BitBlt(hBKDC, 0, 0, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom, hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

   // Reduce lighting
   HDC hBKDC2L = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
   HGDIOBJ hBitmapBK2LOld = SelectObject(hBKDC2L, CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom));
   ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hDesktopDC);
   FillRect(hBKDC2L, &rcDesktop, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
   BLENDFUNCTION bf = {AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 128};
   BOOL b = AlphaBlend(hBKDC, 0, 0, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom, hBKDC2L, 0, 0, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom, bf);
}

// Window procedure of the background window
LRESULT CALLBACK ServiceMonitorThread::BackgroundWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   LRESULT res = FALSE;
   switch (nMessage)
   {
   // Implement WM_PAINT message handler
   case WM_PAINT:
      {
         PAINTSTRUCT ps = {0};
         HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
         RECT rcDesktop = {0};
         GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rcDesktop);
         BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom, hBKDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
         EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
         res = TRUE;
      }
      break;

   // Ignore WM_CLOSE event
   case WM_CLOSE:
      break;

   default:
      res = DefWindowProc(hWnd, nMessage, wParam, lParam);
   }
   return res;
}

// Creates a background window on the current desktop (which will 
// actually be the secondary desktop).
void ServiceMonitorThread::CreateBackgroundWindow()
{
   // Create Window Class
   WNDCLASS wc = {0};
   wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)ServiceMonitorThread::BackgroundWindowProc;
   wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
   wc.lpszClassName = "ErrorDialogBK";
   RegisterClass(&wc);

   // Retrieve desktop size
   RECT rcDesktop = {0};
   GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rcDesktop);

   // Create Background Window
   HWND hBKWindow = CreateWindow("ErrorDialogBK", "",
      WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_DISABLED,
      rcDesktop.left, rcDesktop.top, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom,
      NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a call to `FatalAppExit` with a fairly large text so as to size up the resulting message box.

This message box is system modal, on top of everything except the start screen. You can of course instead create a topmost window (see the windows styles to `CreateWindowEx`). But `FatalAppExit` is the means that Windows provides for this thing.

Comment: But it's not modal though, I have full access to the application and everything else on the desktop/system.\